# How do I make a blueprint run keyboard key commands?

Tags: unreal-4, keyboard, blueprints

I created a project based on the **Top Down Example**.

In the project comes a character that I can move by clicking on the terrain that already comes by default.

**Image of gameplay:**

[image]

In the character's blueprint, I added a function on the **N KEY**. Simply to print a sentence (*key N*).

**Character's blueprint:**

[image]

**I created an NPC based on creating a Blueprint Class > Character:**

[image]

In the NPC blueprint I added a function, only now in the **M KEY**, but with the same principle. Print a sentence (*key M*).

**NPC's Blueprint:**

[image]

**It turns out that only the command made in the blueprint of the character works:**

[image]

*I alternately clicked the **N and M keys** to take the screenshot.*

I scanned the character's blueprint to see if something was missing, something I needed to add in order for the NPC blueprint to recognize the keyboard command. But I only found things like that related to the mouse.

**Scan:**

[image]

I'd like to know what I need to do to make the NPC blueprint recognize the **M KEY**.

Comment: You have to enable input, at the right panel in search box type “input” it will navigate you to the input tab and you will see the option to enable input.

Comment: @ColdSteel In this tab appeared 3 options: Block Input, Auto Receive Input and Input Priority. None of them seem to be the option you mentioned.

Comment: The option I mentioned is obviously the AUTORECIEVEINPUT

Comment: CharacterBP of the top down template already has it on by default - thats why N did work but M didnt

Comment: I made the comment because I compared the input tab of the NPC with that of the character and both were the same. And in the receive option, the box next to it appears disabled, but if I click, it displays numerous player options (player 0 through player 7), and does not activate.

Comment: I tested with all 8 players and none worked.

Comment: strange that it doesnt work for you.

Comment: But in this case - you can just Get an actual input in player controller - and then delegate it to your NPCs.

Comment: The input tab of the character is the same as the NPC's.

Comment: Perhaps it works only on possessed pawns, which would make a lot of sense. Just get the input in PC and delegate it to the NPC.

Comment: “Consume Input” means only the first actor that can receive input, does. Disable consume input to allow multiple actors to receive input. Alternatively, use functions / custom events to make the first actor’s input do things on other actors.

Answer (score 1):

In the Pawn section of your AI Character, you will find the option "AI Controller Class"

[image: AI Controller Class]

You need to create this controller class in Blueprint.  It's not one of the standard options, you'll need to search for it or use the drop down arrows.

[image: AIController AI Controller image]

When you've got this and set up your required options in the Pawn section of your AI Character, you can set the relevant code inside this AI Controller Blueprint.

Comment: I created the class. I put the code inside and then set it in the blueprint of the minion. It did not work out here.

Answer (score 1):

To receive input, you should use a [PlayerController](https://docs.unrealengine.com/4.27/en-US/InteractiveExperiences/Framework/Controller/PlayerController/). You'd want to check "Auto Possess Player" in your pawn and set your [GameMode](https://docs.unrealengine.com/4.27/en-US/InteractiveExperiences/Framework/GameMode/) to use your PlayerController as the default.

However, I'd suspect your new Character receives input and the existing one does not because the new one either has "Auto Possess Player" or is otherwise being possessed by the player and the existing one is not.

In Unreal, a Controller "possesses" a Pawn so it's the thing that can tell it how to behave. So a PlayerController can possess a Pawn and send it commands based on player inputs or an AIController can possess a Pawn and send it commands based on your AI scripting. You can probably use input commands from the Pawn if it's possessed by the PlayerController.